# R Eclipse StatET - Creating wordcloud gets overlapped words

Tags: r, word-cloud

I'm trying to create a wordcloud using R in Eclipse. I've been working with R for some weeks without any problem and I´ve created lots of different plots, but when creating the wordcloud, any kind of them and using different configurations, I always get the wordcloud with all the words overlapped.

I've followed different examples and I always get the words overlapped. For example, if I execute this code:

```
library(wordcloud)
library(tm)

wordcloud("May our children and our children's children to a
            thousand generations, continue to enjoy the benefits conferred
            upon us by a united country, and have cause yet to rejoice under
            those glorious institutions bequeathed us by Washington and his
            compeers.",colors=brewer.pal(6,"Dark2"),random.order=FALSE)
```

I get this result:

[image]

As you can see, all the words are overlapped and I don´t know what to do. I've search a lot on the Internet and I didn't get any clue.

Comment: Nobody can help me with this? I still have the problem. Thanks

Comment: If it helps to get an answer, I've seen that even the `textplot()` function in `wordcloud` package prints the words in the plot overlapped. I hope this help.

Comment: I get a perfectly fine plot in RStudio, maybe you should fill a bug report in Eclipse?

Comment: @RomanLustrik, I think it is an Eclipse bug rather a plotting bug

Answer (score 0):

The arguments within the `wordcloud` package includes:

"`use.r.layout` - if false, then c++ code is used for collision detection, otherwise R is used"
[-Documentation for Wordcloud package.](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud/wordcloud.pdf)

There may be some difficulty with Eclipse and the usage of R vs. C++. As I am unsure as to the default of `Wordcloud` try toggling the argument between `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

e.g. `Wordcloud("Corpus",use.r.layout=TRUE,colors=brewer.pal(6,"Dark2"),random.order=FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem after adding the command

```
Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL','C')
```

Disabling  this directive made wordclouds work fine again.
I am using Jupyter Notebook with R kernel